# How can I tab by ear a song played on another instrument to guitar?

Tags: guitar, instruments

Is it theoretically possible to tab any song/piece from another instrument to the guitar? For example, this song I want to tab("A Kiss From An Old Flame" by Mercury Rev) uses 'flamenco', I think.

I want to know if it's possible to tab to guitar a song done in another instrument.

How should one proceed to do it? Is it the same in guitar where I should find the sound of the bass note and proceed from there? Can I do the tabbing by ear or do something else entirely?

Comment: Have added an answer however your question is a bit confusing - 'flamenco' is a style of music played on guitar so I am not sure what you are asking here.

Comment: Yeah, I guess it is the style of music I'm referring to, but if what's playing on that song is a guitar, I wonder how they achieve that sound.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As long as the piece doesn't have more than six notes played at the same time this is absolutely possible, and even if it does, you could just transcribe the melody, or key notes.

Doesn't even matter what instrument, all that is important is that you can hear or work out the notes. If you have to replay the note over and over again, that is fine, and as you get more familiar with transcribing, you will find it easier.

For chords it can be easiest to first find the bass note, as you mentioned, and work up. Or if the bass is hard to hear, transcribe the higher notes first and play around with possible bass notes to see what fits.